# pygame.mixer.music.set_pos doesn't exist?

Tags: python, pygame, mixer

I'm making a program which when the player dies, gets the music time, and plays a new song using the music time from the previous song, I've done this before a while back and it worked with no problems, but now it's giving me an error message (shown below)

```
    musictime = pygame.mixer.music.get_pos()
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    pygame.mixer.music.load("music3slow.ogg")
    pygame.mixer.music.set_pos(musictime * 2)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

the error I got was this:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'set_pos'
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, like I said it worked when I tried it before, it's probably something stupid but sometimes you just need the eyes of somebody else to see where you've messed up, thanks in advance :)

Comment: It's listed in the [pygame docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html) (version 1.9), but I can't find it in my module (version 1.8), too. Maybe you were using a newer version of pygame back then?

Comment: I'm still using the same version of python and pygame; literally nothing has changed :(

Comment: See if running this from the command line works: `python -c "import pygame; print(pygame.mixer.music.set_pos)"`.  That should give the same traceback.  If not, something really weird is going on.

Comment: python 2.7 with the latest supported version of pygame, i cant remember the version number for pygame right now

Comment: @user3254643 - Use [`pygame.version.ver`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.version.ver) to get the version number.

Comment: @iCodez  pygame 1.9.1

Comment: did you checked, you are not using `pygame.mixer.xxx.set_pos()` anywhere else, with a typo or something? probably problem is not it but still, better to check.

Comment: @Lafexlos just checked and this is the only time i've used it

Comment: FIXED IT GUYS, for some reason set_pos() still doesnt work but I figured out doing pygame.mixer.music.play(0,(musictime / 1000) * 2) did the same thing I wanted it to! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: That's good to hear. :) I am no expert in here but I think you should answer your own question and accept it. It will be much better than staying as "unanswered".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if set_pos() doesn't work try

`pygame.mixer.music.play(0,(put what you need here)`

I don't know why set_pos() sometimes doesn't work but the play option will and it does the same thing as set_pos

Answer (score 1):

*set_pos* doesn't exist because it's a new method in 1.9.2. You have *pygame* version 1.9.1 according to your comments.

from https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.set_pos

> pygame.mixer.music.set_pos()
>
> ... *description*...
>
> Function set_pos() calls underlining SDL_mixer function
>   Mix_SetMusicPosition.
>
> **New in Pygame 1.9.2**